# Fields are missing in Lightning Experience for Tasks/Log a Call/Events. Any workaround for this?

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-field

My question could be a duplicate of the below question that was not answered.

[Email and Phone Task fields are missing in lightning experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197324/email-and-phone-task-fields-are-missing-in-lightning-experience)

Just added a custom field in Activity object using Salesforce classic. Standard Comments and the custom field meant to be available on Task layout.

I switched back to Lightning Experience and tried to verify it. But, I have not found those two fields (the standard Comments field and the custom field which I have created).

Please guide me on how to bring those two fields in Lightning Experience. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your problem? I added a custom field on Activity to the Task layout and could see that in LEX. The only difference here was that I added the fields to the layout being in LEX.

Comment: Thanks, @JayantDas for your reply. Can you please let me know how to find the layout which is meant for LEX? Where should I have to go and see?

Comment: I added detailed steps as an answer with screenshots, as how I was able to add a custom field on Activity and be able to display it on both Task and Event. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a custom field on Activity and add that on Task and Event page layouts while being in Lightning Experience. Have detailed out the scenarios with screenshots as how I was able to do this. All these steps were carried out in Lightning Experience (LEX).

**Scenario 1** - While adding a field on Activity

1. From Setup --> Object Manager --> Activity: Added a custom field on Activity
2. While adding the field, selected the field to be available for both Task and Event layout
3. Verified on a Task/Event record, that the fields were available

[image]

**Scenario 2** - When field is already added on Activity, but not available on the Task/Event layouts

1. Navigate to a Task/Event record
2. From Setup gear icon, click on Edit Object
3. When in Object Manager, go to the Page layout, add the field as required and it reflects on the record

[image]

Comment: The required checkbox is not editable I can't check it. My DateTime formula field is showing up in the classic page layout of my custom object but it doesn't show in lightning.